# Can the gap in my plot be reduced or eliminated?

Tags: plotting

The following plot

```
With[{staffcr = 0.45, othercr = 0.125, papp = 1.0 (2/12), pdata = 1.0 (23370/12)}, 
  ContourPlot[
    -88120.` + 0.95000` ndata pdata - 1.0` ndata othercr pdata - 
    1.0` ndata pdata staffcr - 
      11542.58115183246` napp papp (-0.9500000000000001` + othercr + staffcr) - 
      0.9999999999999999` 
        Max[15000, 0.08833053395066709` (2204633 napp + 9550 ndata)^0.646`] == 
    0, 
    {napp, 0, 400}, {ndata, 0, 400}]]
```

produces a gap or discontinuous jump in my plot. The reason seems to be the use of `Max` in the formula.

The question is, can the gap be made smaller using some setting about axis, perhaps, or is Mathematica revealing a precise jump?

[image]

Comment: Try to play with the option PlotPoints gradually increasing its value untill the gap decreases to your liking. Even a better idea is to wrap the expression under the contour plot by `Rationalize`. It removes the gap even without specifying the PlotPoints.

Comment: Have you tried `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: The code you posted does produce to the plot you show. Please correct your post to make them correspond.

Answer (score 2):

The gap you see is caused by a singularity is given by the implicit function:

```
0.088331 (2204633 napp + 9550 ndata)^(323/500) == 15000
```

Let's take a close look at your expression in the area of the gap and
draw a plot that includes both your curve and singularly curve.

```
With[{staffcr = 0.45, othercr = 0.125, papp = 1.0 (2/12), pdata = 1.0 (23370/12)}, 
  ContourPlot[
    {-88120. + 0.95 ndata pdata - ndata othercr pdata - ndata pdata staffcr - 
       11542.581152 napp papp (-0.95 + othercr + staffcr) - 
       Max[15000, 0.088331 (2204633 napp + 9550 ndata)^0.646] == 0,
     0.088331 (2204633 napp + 9550 ndata)^(323/500) == 15000},
    {napp, 50, 60}, {ndata, 80, 95},
    ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
    FrameLabel -> {napp, ndata},
    Epilog -> Text["Line of discontinuity", Offset[{40, 0}, {56.5, 90.}]]]]
```

[image: combined_plot]

I think your plot is better presented this way than by removing the gap with the option `Exclusions -> None`, because this way gives the viewer a better idea of what is going on. However, should you prefer removal, that is accomplish as mentioned in comments to your question:

```
With[{staffcr = 0.45, othercr = 0.125, papp = 1.0 (2/12), pdata = 1.0 (23370/12)}, 
 ContourPlot[-88120. + 0.95 ndata pdata - ndata othercr pdata - 
    ndata pdata staffcr - 
    11542.581152 napp papp (-0.95 + othercr + staffcr) - 
    Max[15000, 0.088331 (2204633 napp + 9550 ndata)^0.646] == 0,
  {napp, 50, 60}, {ndata, 80, 95},
  Exclusions -> None]]
```